# Why extra LSTM layer is getting bad results than normal LSTM model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am creating a Keras model. I am trying to variations. 
That is my first model:

```
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss')
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100,input_shape=(TIME_STEPS,11), dropout=0.0,
               recurrent_dropout=0.0, kernel_initializer='random_uniform'
              ))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
#######model.add(LSTM(64))
model.add(Dense(15, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=kr.optimizers.rmsprop(0.01),
              metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy()])

csv_logger = kr.callbacks.CSVLogger('sonuclar.log')

history = model.fit(x_train,  #train girdiler
                    y_train,  #train çıktılar
                    epochs=150,
                    verbose=2,
                    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                    shuffle=False,
                    validation_data=(x_test1,
                                     y_test1),
                    callbacks=[EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=21),
             ModelCheckpoint(filepath='best_model.h5', monitor='val_loss', save_best_only=True)])
```

And this model have just 1 Lstm layer and 2 dense layer. That is my loss results:

```
.
.
.
Epoch 99/150
 - 0s - loss: 8.0949e-04 - binary_accuracy: 4.9048e-04 - val_loss: 3.7912e-04 - val_binary_accuracy: 4.8986e-04
Epoch 100/150
 - 0s - loss: 7.9101e-04 - binary_accuracy: 4.9053e-04 - val_loss: 9.9216e-05 - val_binary_accuracy: 4.8991e-04
Epoch 101/150
 - 0s - loss: 6.8317e-04 - binary_accuracy: 4.9057e-04 - val_loss: 3.0611e-04 - val_binary_accuracy: 4.8996e-04
Epoch 102/150
 - 0s - loss: 9.5524e-04 - binary_accuracy: 4.9061e-04 - val_loss: 7.6808e-05 - val_binary_accuracy: 4.9000e-04
Epoch 103/150
 - 0s - loss: 6.7897e-04 - binary_accuracy: 4.9065e-04 - val_loss: 2.7978e-04 - val_binary_accuracy: 4.9005e-04
Epoch 104/150
 - 0s - loss: 5.9103e-04 - binary_accuracy: 4.9069e-04 - val_loss: 6.1831e-04 - val_binary_accuracy: 4.9009e-04
Epoch 105/150
 - 0s - loss: 8.2365e-04 - binary_accuracy: 4.9072e-04 - val_loss: 6.4325e-05 - val_binary_accuracy: 4.9014e-04
Epoch 106/150
 - 0s - loss: 7.1716e-04 - binary_accuracy: 4.9076e-04 - val_loss: 1.0926e-04 - val_binary_accuracy: 4.9018e-04
Epoch 107/150
 - 0s - loss: 6.5435e-04 - binary_accuracy: 4.9080e-04 - val_loss: 2.2587e-04 - val_binary_accuracy: 4.9022e-04
Epoch 108/150
 - 0s - loss: 7.6734e-04 - binary_accuracy: 4.9083e-04 - val_loss: 7.6250e-05 - val_binary_accuracy: 4.9026e-04
Epoch 109/150
 - 0s - loss: 6.4531e-04 - binary_accuracy: 4.9087e-04 - val_loss: 5.4440e-04 - val_binary_accuracy: 4.9030e-04
Epoch 110/150
 - 0s - loss: 7.2096e-04 - binary_accuracy: 4.9091e-04 - val_loss: 8.7251e-05 - val_binary_accuracy: 4.9034e-04
Epoch 111/150
 - 0s - loss: 7.3333e-04 - binary_accuracy: 4.9094e-04 - val_loss: 2.8440e-04 - val_binary_accuracy: 4.9038e-04
Epoch 112/150
```

If I try to use a second Lstm layer this model should be smart than previous model for predicting stock prices but this code:

```
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss')
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100,input_shape=(TIME_STEPS,11), dropout=0.0,
               recurrent_dropout=0.0, kernel_initializer='random_uniform'
              ,return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(LSTM(64))
model.add(Dense(15, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=kr.optimizers.rmsprop(0.01),
              metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy()])

csv_logger = kr.callbacks.CSVLogger('sonuclar.log')

history = model.fit(x_train,  #train girdiler
                    y_train,  #train çıktılar
                    epochs=150,
                    verbose=2,
                    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                    shuffle=False,
                    validation_data=(x_test1,
                                     y_test1),
                    callbacks=[EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=21),
             ModelCheckpoint(filepath='best_model.h5', monitor='val_loss', save_best_only=True)])
```

has bad training result than previous model. This can't be overfitting because I dont use predicting. Why second model is bad than first model.
Last one, my data set have 15 stock price features and I am trying to predict stock prices

Comment: Hi @oğuz bozkurt, kindly include minimum reproducible code and if possible the dataset you used.

Answer (score 0):

Adding more components to the neural network does not necessarily mean that you are going to improve upon simpler models on your task. Such things are considered as design decisions (like *hyperparameters setting*) that you need to experiment with your task, and dataset to end up finding the optimal decisions.

Actually, by adding more modules (like the second LSTM network you just added), you're increasing the model parameters that have to be trained ––also, you will have to give more time to your network to get trained. When the model parameters are getting large in count, the model gets more complex, having hard time fitting on the training instances as it needs to optimize parameters in a way that can optimally fit the training instances.